# The matrix norm of the identity matrix disturbed by a small matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

So I am consider the norm of matrix $\|I-C\|_2$, where $C$ is a positive definite matrix with a very small norm, what can we say about $\|I-C\|_2$? Like, is it smaller than $1$? Or can I express it w.r.t $C$?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am considering two-norm specifically

Comment: yeah exactly. the one induced by vector norms, or the sqrt of the greatest eigenvalue of AA^T

Comment: yeah sorry for the typo, edited.

Comment: You are essentially asking whether $\lVert\cdot \rVert_2$ is differentiable, which should be the case away from the null matrix, try searching this site. Once you know that $\lVert\cdot \rVert_2$ is differentiable, let $f(\epsilon)=\lVert I-\epsilon C\rVert_2$. The Taylor expansion will give you $$f(\epsilon)=1 +\epsilon f'(0)+o(\epsilon), $$ which should be enough for your purposes.

Comment: BTW, the same question with the Frobenius norm is much easier, because that one comes from a scalar product.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_n$ be the set of $n\times n$ real symmetric matrices.

$X\in S_n\mapsto ||X||_2=\rho(X)$ is continuous but not differentiable in a neighborhood of some $X$ which has several eigenvalues $\lambda,\mu$ s.t. $|\lambda|=|\mu|=\rho(X)$.

Here $||I-C||_2=1-\lambda<1$ where $\lambda=\min(spectrum(C))$.

Comment: Oh really, it is *not* differentiable?!? I suggested that this was not the case in the comments. It seems that I was wrong. Thank you, I learned something

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro  , yes. take for example $X(t)=diag(t,-t^2)$ in a neighborhood of $t=1$. $\rho(X)=t$ when $t\leq 1$ and $\rho(X)=t^2$ when $t\geq 1$. The derivative does not exist in $t=1$.

Comment: That's a very clear example, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since matrix $\rm C$ is symmetric and positive definite "with a very small norm",

$$\alpha \, \mathrm I \preceq \mathrm C \preceq \beta \, \mathrm I$$

where $0 < \alpha < \beta \ll 1$. Hence,

$$- \beta \, \mathrm I \preceq -\mathrm C \preceq - \alpha \, \mathrm I$$

and

$$(1 - \beta) \, \mathrm I \preceq \mathrm I - \mathrm C \preceq (1 - \alpha) \, \mathrm I$$

Thus,

$$\| \mathrm I - \mathrm C \|_2 = \sigma_{\max} \left( \mathrm I - \mathrm C \right) = \lambda_{\max} \left( \mathrm I - \mathrm C \right) = 1 - \lambda_{\min} \left( \mathrm C \right) = 1 - \alpha < 1$$

which agrees with Loup Blanc's answer.

Comment: In retrospect, it would have been much more straightforward to use the spectral decomposition.